# Disable push notification in specific view controller in foreground?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

I am implementing a chat feature in an app. Right now every push I am using this to show notification while using app:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
}
```

I am wondering if it is possible to disable push notification from showing at top, while maintaining the buzzer for a specific view controller?

If yes, what should I do to create it?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: SH_khan answer worked for me

Answer (score 3):

Implement it like this:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

...

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    if wantToShow {
         completionHandler([.alert, .sound])
    } else {
         completionHandler([])
    }
}
```

Then change `wantToShow` according to the current state.

Comment: `didReceiveRemoteNotification` function is not called if I use `completionHandler([])`